# C++, check if input value is a specific character

Tags: c++, char

I have the following question. I want to read user's input which should be only two char R or B. How do I make a correctly working while loop to control that the user inputs only this two characters and nothing else. If it's wrong asks the user for an input again. Thank you very much.

```
cout<< "Enter R or B: ";
        cin >> letter;

        while(cin.fail()) {   
                        cin.clear(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `do-while`:

```
do {
    cin.clear();
    cout<< "Enter R or B: ";
    cin >> letter;

} while (letter != 'R' && letter != 'B');
```

That ensures that your program will be run at least once. In the checking, simply check if the letter is not `R` and also not `B`, you repeat the loop.